# How long does AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) last?

Tags: iphone, vibration, iphone-vibrate

I don't have access an iPhone to test on right now.  Can anyone tell me how long this call makes the phone vibrate?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article at http://www.kimballlarsen.com/2009/12/22/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-for-a-long-time/ states that:

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) API call will produce exactly **0.4** seconds of vibration and **0.1** seconds of silence.